# why ridge regression with alph=0 is not the same as normal linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In theory ridge regression with alpha=0 should have the same coefficients as linear regression but in sklearn python they are slighly different. anyone has idea why this happens? (datasets are normalized)

```
linear_regressor = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
linear_regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_train_prime = linear_regressor.predict(X_train)
linear_regressor_MSE = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_prime,Y_train)


ridge_regressor = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=0, fit_intercept=False)
ridge_regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_train_prime_ridge = ridge_regressor.predict(X_train)
ridge_regressor_MSEmetrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_prime_ridge,Y_train)
```

Comment: Please update your question by *showing* what exactly are the differences; even better, use an openly available dataset and construct a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As is, there is no much sense at showing us the commands for the MSE etc for some unknown to us dataset without sharing also the actual results...

Comment: Can be (from here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html):
solver, random_state, tol, max_iter

Try firstly solver='lsqr'. And also better to add some information on how different are the weights.